# How does one control the locally accessible port for the registry addon when running minikube under docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm new to kubernetes and trying to get started.  On my dev machine I'm running minikube using the docker driver.  On startup I get the following spew:

```
  minikube v1.27.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 (amd64)
  minikube 1.28.0 is available! Download it: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.28.0
  To disable this notice, run: 'minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false'

✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.25.2 on Docker 20.10.18 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.7.0
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
    ▪ Using image docker.io/kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.8
    ▪ Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1
    ▪ Using image k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.1
    ▪ Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.2.1
    ▪ Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1
╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                                      │
│    Registry addon with docker driver uses port 32795 please use that instead of default port 5000    │
│                                                                                                      │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
  For more information see: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/google_containers/kube-registry-proxy:0.4
    ▪ Using image docker.io/registry:2.8.1
  Verifying ingress addon...
  Verifying registry addon...
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass, metrics-server, dashboard, ingress, registry
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

Note that the registry addon attempts to use port 5000 but, since that port is in use on my system, it assigns an available high range port, in this example 32795.  My (oversimplified) understanding is that minikube starts the various services in what are conceptually ssomething like separate miniature containers within minikube, each service is addressable by a separate internally ranged ip (10.x.x.x) and the minikube deployment then maps exposed ports for those services to ports that can be addressed from the host machine (so svc/registry 80 is mapped such that minikube 5000 will hit it.  But since minikube is running in docker, there's an additional mapping such that it goes something like 127.0.0.1:32795->minikube:5000->svc/registry:80.

The assigned port changes whenever minikube starts.  I can build and push docker images to the registry using this port:

```
$ docker build -t 127.0.0.1:30400/jenkins:2.303.2-lts -f kubernetes-ci-cd/applications/jenkins/Dockerfile kuber
netes-ci-cd/applications/jenkins
$ docker push 127.0.0.1:32795/jenkins:2.303.2-lts
```

I would like to have this bound to a stable port.  Changing the configuration (in the container under /etc/kubernetes/addons/registry-svc.yaml) doesn't work since that folder is not persisted and any changes to it just get blown away on startup.  I've tried saving a local copy of the file and applying it after startup, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$ kubectl apply -f ~/registry-svc.yaml
service/registry configured
```

Rebinding the port-forward

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system svc/registry 30400:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:30400 -> 5000
Forwarding from [::1]:30400 -> 5000
```

Changes the port binding for minikube, it looks like (it breaks pushing images to the registry, anyway, presumably because the old port is no longer the correct one) but it's running in a docker container so, since 30400 wasn't exposed at startup and there's no way to expose a port on a running container, attempting to push to that port gets connection refused.  I can probably come up with some sort of workaround like persisting the /etc/kubernetes/addons folder, but it kinda feels like that can't really be the right solution since configuration changes from default must be a common thing and if they were a common thing then the configuration folder would have been persisted by default.  What is the "correct" solution for controlling which port services (such as the registry, although this is going to become an issue with other, non-addon services as soon as I solve this problem) are bound to and exposed when running minikube under docker?

Comment: Hi `John Cuyle` can you provide information on where you are deploying this minikube cluster like on a server or on your local machine..?